# How to make a function overload generic to strongly type its implementation parameters?

Tags: typescript, generics, polymorphism, overloading

I'm trying to find a way to get a strict parameters discrimination from a function overload. Obviously my issue with this implementation is that my generic type `T` can be extended to anything inheriting `AorB` props so the error I get here is perfectly expected (`'{ type: "A"; a: any; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'AorB'.`).

What I'm looking for is a way to have a sort of `<T implements AorB>` so that when the parameter `type` equals `"A"`, the `customProps` parameter is discriminated as `A` props.

I'm also trying to avoid resorting to use `any` within the function implementation parameters or `as` within the returns.

```
type A = {
  a: string
  type: 'A'
}

type B = {
  b: string
  type: 'B'
}

type AorB = A | B

function createAorB(type: A['type'], customProps?: Partial<Omit<A, 'type'>>): A
function createAorB(type: B['type'], customProps?: Partial<Omit<B, 'type'>>): B
function createAorB<T extends AorB>(type: T['type'], customProps: Partial<Omit<T, 'type'>> = {}): T {
  if (type === 'A') {
    return {
      type,
      a: customProps.a || '',
    }
  }

  return {
    type,
    b: customProps.b || '',
  }
}

const newA = createAorB('A')
const newB = createAorB('B')
```

**UPDATE**

If I enforce `AorB` as the return value:

```
function createAorB<T extends AorB>(type: T['type'], customProps: Partial<Omit<T, 'type'>> = {}): AorB
```

I get both errors `Property 'a' does not exist on type 'Partial<Omit<T, "type">>'.` and `Property 'b' does not exist on type 'Partial<Omit<T, "type">>'.` on the respective `customProps.a` and `customProps.b` lines.

Comment: The argument list to `createAorB` is a discriminated union, and you can write it out so that the compiler sees that, [like this](https://tsplay.dev/WJypgm).  Does this meet your needs? If so I could write out an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That's brilliant! I had no idea the `infer` keyword existed in Typescript. I get the basic idea but I will have to read more about how that works. You can indeed make it an answer because it perfectly solves my issue :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument list [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of `createAOrB()` forms a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), where the first tuple element is the *discriminant*.  It looks like this:

```
type Args = 
   [type: "A", customProps?: Partial<Omit<A, "type">>] | 
   [type: "B", customProps?: Partial<Omit<B, "type">>];
```

If you use a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to assign the elements to variables named `type` and `customProps`, you can [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) the rest parameter as `Args`, and then [the compiler will use control flow analysis to narrow `customProps` when you check `type`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-6.html#control-flow-analysis-for-destructured-discriminated-unions):

```
function createAorB(type: A['type'], customProps?: Partial<Omit<A, 'type'>>): A
function createAorB(type: B['type'], customProps?: Partial<Omit<B, 'type'>>): B
function createAorB(...[type, customProps]: Args) {
  if (type === 'A') {
    return {
      type,
      a: customProps?.a || '', // okay
    }
  }

  return {
    type,
    b: customProps?.b || '', // okay
  }
}
```

---

If you happen to have lots of types in `AorB` and not just `A | B`, it might be tedious to extend the `Args` definition.  In this case you can have the compiler compute it for you as a function of `AorB`, like this:

```
type Args = AorB extends infer T ? T extends AorB ? (
  [type: T['type'], customProps?: Partial<Omit<T, 'type'>>]
) : never : never;
```

This uses [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to copy `AorB` into a new [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T`, which is then used to make a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) so that `[type: T['type'], customProps?: Partial<Omit<T, 'type'>>]` automatically becomes a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) if `T` is a union type (it *distributes* the operation over unions in `T`).

You can verify that it evaluates to the same as the manually defined version above.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUCGAuKBnYATgJYB2A5mlKJDgOQy0oC+KK10AQgspQEY75i5SuzodGLNuGgwA9gS6I4AHygdW7WATK5uchVAgAPYBBIATXaQBmEAlAAqUAPyPDJs5djyurgBSUANqijoG07LQAugA0UADGAK74sgC2AAoEsmC4zjhpGATARBgANgA8APIpRMBlDrHh0rQAfM2RKACUUDgkEABudt1QvQMEANysAPQAVFTSWjrclFDB0jgARDDrsYnJ6ZnZuVD5hcXlVTVlMLHr7OutUKoJFhDWpBDmkY9Qy6s0UOsONt4klgKkMlkcnkCkVSpVqrUODc7g8ni83r1Pj9ppNWNZnnEirISPECBAMKZ9Bw-CEYGEIjEQXsIYdoac4RdatcoI1IC1mh0cDAUPiSISiMTSeTKT4aWs1PSmozdmD9pCjidYecEWUkTyIq1BWoRQSiSS4mSKRAqX4AHT2v4QHag8EHXCRIXaXBdVDoIjWKByyAIeCIei0H3LKBk4AJAgk33oJPsaJR9DYJmqlk5W0YR6qWi0VNJqAsdCSdAxuMJqMpqP8TOu9W23j5nlFygsSRxYn4YYQADucEQFul1tl4Y6KB7JD7vQHiilVpttHEHSAA)